# Select URL in HTML table with regular expression

Tags: regex, url, html-table

I have a table with names and URLs like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>name1</td>
  <td>www.url.com</td> </tr>
<tr>
  <td>name2</td>
<td>www.url2.com</td> </tr>
```

I want to select all URL-tabledata in a table.
I tried:

```
<td>w{3,3}.*(</td>){1,1}
```

But this expression doesn't "stop" at the first `</td>`. I get:

```
<td>www.url.com</td> </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>name2</td>
    <td>www.url2.com</td>
```

as result. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to match a URL. I'll try the simplest to your needs: just correcting your regex. You can use this one instead:

```
<td>w{3}.*?</td>
```

Explanation:

```
<td>          # this part is ok
w{3,3}        # the notation {3} is simpler for this case and has the same effect
.*            # the main problem: you have to use .*? to make .* non-greedy, that
                is, to make it match as little as possible
(</td>){1,1}  # same as second line. As the number is 1, {1} is not needed
```

Comment: Note: If you just want to **match the just URL part** (without the `td`s), you can use a look behind and a look ahead: `(?<=<td>)w{3}.*?(?=</td>)`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be

```
\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

or

```
"((((ht{2}ps?://)?)((w{3}\\.)?))?)[^.&&[a-zA-Z0-9]][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[^.&&[a-zA-Z0-9]](\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})"
```

See this link - [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url). Many answers are available.

Comment: Thx for your fast reply. I already tried this regex. Notepad++ said that he can find this regex.. What can i do?